# How to mock useEffect async calls with react-native-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to test the screen that has useEffect hook with the following:

```
export const SomeScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {

  const [isSensorAvailable, setIsSensorAvailable] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isSensorAvailableCheck = async () => {
      try {
        await FingerprintScanner.isSensorAvailable();
        setIsSensorAvailable(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    isSensorAvailableCheck();
  }, []);
  
  ...
   Here goes code that renders View if the sensor is available
  ...
}
```

And I'm trying the following test:

```
import {default as FingerprintScannerMock} from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';

jest.mock('react-native-fingerprint-scanner');

(FingerprintScannerMock.isSensorAvailable as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(true);

const createTestProps = (props: Object) => ({
  navigation: {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  },
  ...props,
});

describe('Testing some screen', () => {

   test('testing some functionalities', async () => {
     let props: any;
    props = createTestProps({});

    const component = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RegisterPasswordScreen {...props} />
      </Provider>,
    );

    const {getByText, getByTestId, getAllByTestId} = component;

    const container = getByTestId('containerId');

    expect(container).toBeTruthy();
   });

});
```

But this container is never found because *setIsSensorIsAvailable* never sets the value to *true* because of the following error:

`An update to SomeScreen inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

I tried everything even like this:

```
  const component = await waitFor(() =>
       render(<Provider store={store}>
         <RegisterPasswordScreen {...props} />
        </Provider>,
       );
   );
```

But when I run this test it never ends. Tried also to wrap it with `act(...)` but that does not work either, then the error is following:
`Can't access .root on unmounted test renderer`.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue

Wrapping the component using act(https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) solved my issue

Using create to wrap your component for react native instead of using a typical render method wrapped in act

```
import { act, create } from 'react-test-renderer';


it('test', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
        create(<ComponentWithAsyncUseEffect />);
    });
})
```

Comment: the it should be async if you want to await inside of it

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `findByTestId` rather than `getByTestId` and now it works well.

Comment: For those curious, the reason `find` works instead of `get` is that `find` returns a promise and retries until the element is located or the timeout hits. You can also use `waitFor` to test components with asynchronous lifecycles. See [About Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/) for details.